# android concatenating string value name to an expression

Tags: java, android

Am trying to attach a resource string name to an expression but can't  get going. My code is below:The erorr occurs specifically in the `createFromResource` method's argument `R.array.+ precedingDigitsIdentifier`. Any workaround?

```
public void createPrecedingDigitsSpinner(String selectedCountry){

         String selectedCntry =selectedCountry.toLowerCase();

        /**confirm that value of this
         * country exist in countries.xml**/
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
        String precedingDigitsIdentifier  = selectedCntry + "_preceding_digits";

        try{
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),*R.array.+ precedingDigitsIdentifier*,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        }catch (Resources.NotFoundException e){


            CharSequence text = "the selected country contains no preceding digits data try another time";
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: In the code I'm seeing *R.array instead of "R.array

Answer (score 1):

You can't concatenate a variable name and expect it to work. Rather, you'll need to use a different method:

```
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
    getResources().getIdentifier(precedingDigitsIdentifier, "drawable", getPackageName()),
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

This will get the resource ID by a lookup rather than using the Java identifier, which allows you to use a String that is the result of a concatenation.